# Creating a CKAN Extension Error: No such command 'create'

Tags: command-line

I'm Creating a CKAN EXTENSION base in their official documentation.

> https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/theming/templates.html#creating-a-ckan-extension

When I'm in this step,

> ckan -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini create -t ckanext-example_theme

I got this error.

```
(default) root@ccgeo:/usr/lib/ckan/default/src# ckan -c
/etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini create -t ckanext-example_theme 
2021-10-27 02:27:45,515 INFO [ckan.cli] Using configuration file /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini 
2021-10-27 02:27:45,515 INFO [ckan.config.environment] Loading static files from public 2021-10-27
02:27:45,544 INFO [ckan.config.environment] Loading templates from /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates 
2021-10-27 02:27:45,762 INFO [ckan.config.environment] Loading templates from /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates 
Usage: ckan [OPTIONS]
COMMAND [ARGS]... Error: No such command 'create'. (default)
root@ccgeo:/usr/lib/ckan/default/src#
```

Any Help.

Comment: Format the error correctly, using code formatting and not blockquote formatting

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why do you run commands as root? How `ckan` was installed?

Comment: @N0rbert Ubuntu server 20.04 I just read their documentation https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/theming/templates.html#creating-a-ckan-extension